# Set user permissions from settings file in django

Tags: django

I have the following menu in my `settings.py` file:

```
ADMIN_MENU = [
    {
        'name': 'Users',
        'models': [
            'User',
            'Message',
            'Payment',
        ],
        'icon': 'icon-user'
    },
    {
        'name': 'Inventory',
        'models': [
            'Country',
            'Server',
            'Package',
            'blog.post'
        ],
        'icon':'icon-user'
    },
    {
        'name': 'Blog',
        'models': [
            'Post',
        ],
        'icon':'icon-user'
    },
    {
        'name': 'Reports',
        'models': [
            ('Users', '/console/reports/users'),
            ('Usage', '/console/reports/usage'),
        ],
        'icon':'icon-user'
    }
]
```

Now, what I'd like to do, is:
- if a user is *superuser* let him see the entire menu
- if a user is *part of stuff* (`is_staff`) allow him to see only the `Reports` part.

Can I do this directly from my `settings.py` file ? If this is not possible, how can I achieve what I want ?

I'll provide any other info if needed.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible from the settings file (not that I know off any way).

you can easily fix this in the menu template. In my case I would only want superusers to be able to see the admin dashboard link.

```
{% if request.user.is_superuser %}
    <a href="{% url 'admin:index' %}">Admin dashboard</a>
{% endif %}
```

the `is_staff` is not needed unless you want them to have access to the `Admin dashboard`

There are multiple options to restrict the user from accessing the url itself.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/#topic-authorization

easy example is using the `permission_required` decorator

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import permission_required

@permission_required('polls.can_vote')
def my_view(request):
    ...
```

Comment: I read the documentation. I am aware of `@permission_required` decorator but it doesn't help me in my case

Comment: if this is not helping how are you planning on using your `ADMIN_MENU` ? in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/ there is no reference to it.